# Import multiple CSV files into Excel with C# (columns)

Tags: c#, excel, csv

C# using Visual Studio 2017 Community.  This is a WinFormsApp.

Edit for clarity: My goal is to create a single Excel spreadsheet with data extracted from text files. In this case, the text files are RPT files (report files from a measurement system).  My current code works, but it's only halfway there. What it currently does is to take all the individual RPT files from a given directory, and create individual CSV files for each one.

So now, I'm not sure which path to go down: either rewrite my current code to output directly to Excel, OR add to current code to import CSV files into Excel. Either way, I need some help.

My current code works, in that it takes each text file (a report file, RPT file) and creates a corresponding CSV file.  I'm wondering if I went down the wrong path initially by doing this.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir;
        string serialNumber;
        //string infile;
        string outfile;
        string featureName;
        string result;

        // Prompt the user to navigate to and select a directory where RPT files reside
        FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
        DialogResult folder = folderDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (folder == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // dir is the full path to the file, excluding the filename
            dir = folderDlg.SelectedPath;
            fileNameTextBox.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath;
            Environment.SpecialFolder root = folderDlg.RootFolder;

            // Get all the RPT files in the specified directory; do NOT look through sub-directories
            //string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.RPT", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.RPT", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                // serialnumber is the filename WITHOUT the extension and WITHOUT the path to the file included.
                serialNumber = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

                // Create an output CSV file for each serial number; put in same directory as RPT files.
                outfile = dir + "\\" + serialNumber + ".CSV";
                //}

                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
                var csv = new StringBuilder();

                // In first row of every file, put serial number
                var topLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", "", serialNumber);
                csv.AppendLine(topLine);

                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Lines containg the string "---" are result lines.  The data we need is in this line.
                    //if (lines[i].Contains("  ---") || lines[i].Contains("+--"))  
                    if (lines[i].Contains("---"))
                    {
                        // The first feature of each page needs special treatment, because that's where the header is.
                        // "Actual   Nominal  Difference  ... etc.," which appears at the top of every RPT file page.
                        // and because -- in these cases -- the  Feature Name is not directly above the result line.
                        //
                        // So, check the line directly above the result line for the length of the line.
                        // If the length of this line > 50, we know that it's the header line.
                        // In these cases, the featureName is one row above the header line.
                        //if (lines[i-1].Length > 50)

                        // Let's try a different method to identify first feature on each page.
                        // Instead of looking at Length of line, let's look at the entire string
                        // to see if the substring "Actual   Nominal" is in the line
                        // If it is, we've found the first feature of a page.
                        if (lines[i - 1].Contains("Actual   Nominal"))
                        {
                            featureName = lines[i - 2].Trim().ToString();
                            featureNameTextBox.Text = featureName;
                            result = lines[i].Substring(12, 10).Trim().ToString();
                            resultTextBox.Text = result;
                            var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", featureName, result);
                            csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            featureName = lines[i - 1].Trim().ToString();
                            featureNameTextBox.Text = featureName;
                            result = lines[i].Substring(12, 10).Trim().ToString();
                            resultTextBox.Text = result;
                            var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", featureName, result);
                            csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Once outside loop, write to file
                File.WriteAllText(outfile, csv.ToString());
            }
        }

    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

I'd like to create a single Excel spreadsheet, where the first 2 columns are the first two columns as shown in my CSV files, and where subsequent columns in the Excel sheet are the second column ONLY from my current CSV files.  I'd like to go right from the RPT files to Excel, but I'm not sure if that's the easier way to go at this point.

Here's some screenshots that might explain things better.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx5OO.jpg

Comment: It is not clear if the input files are indeed CSVs or "simple text files", but either way, cant you read the first file then combine the parts of the others to a `List<T>` and then output the CSV?  Its not clear what the problem is

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The initial files are RPT files (simple text files).  The current code takes all the RPT files it finds in a directory, and creates a CSV file for each. This is not the ultimate goal.  The ultimate goal is to create an Excel spreadsheet that has all the necessary data in the RPT files.                                  So, I either need to rework my current code to write directly to Excel, OR add to my current code to combine the CSV files into one Excel sheet.  I included a link (at the end) that shows screenshots of the issue.